# SESSION variable in while loop not being sent correctly to second .php file

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, session-variables

I'm trying to create a simple topic and posting system and I have two tables in a MySQL database; a topics table and a posts table. In my posts table I have a post_parentID field that links to a topic_id field in my topics table.

Here is how I start my query selecting (and displaying) all the topics that are in the topic table. I then save the topic_id field into a variable:

```
<?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics INNER JOIN members ON topics.topic_by = members.id";
 $topics = $mysqli->query($sql);

  if ($topics->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each topic
  while($row = $topics->fetch_assoc()) {

 //Saving TopicID into variable
   $topic_id = $row["topic_id"];
   $_SESSION['topicid'] = $topic_id;?>
```

Right after I display the html for each topic, I start a new while loop to display each post within each topic:

```
<?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN members ON posts.post_by = members.id WHERE post_parentID = $topic_id";
 $posts = $mysqli->query($sql);

 if ($posts->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each post
 while($row = $posts->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
```

Right after this, I display the html for each post and then I display the form-control to enter a post, which is directed to a send_post.php file:

```
 <div class="chat-message-form">
  <div class="form-group">
   <form action="includes/send_post.php" method="post">
     <textarea class="form-control message-input" name="post_content" placeholder="Enter message text"></textarea>
      <input type="submit">
      </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

When I call $topic_id in my send_post.php file like this:

```
$topic_id = $_SESSION['topicid'];
```

It only returns the very last topic_id in my topics table instead of the current topic_id in the while loop. Is my logic about this right or should I be doing something different?

Comment: use `session_start();` on top just after `<?php`

Comment: about your logic, you are running loop and trying to load VALUES in session, offcourse you will only get last topic_id, Arrays will be the solution here

Comment: Or you can give it a shot with this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics INNER JOIN members ON topics.topic_by = members.id ORDER BY topic_id DESC";` I'm not sure it will work or not.

Comment: Adding the order by didn't seem to work :(. I'm still confused though, if I am loading values in session and directing that to my second php file all within a while loop, shouldn't it be sending the corresponding topic_id?

Comment: @Aces It is sending but only 1 id, to send multiple ids you need to set Array as suggested by Osuwariboy in his answer

Answer (score 0):

By doing this in your loop:

```
$_SESSION['topicid'] = $topic_id;
```

you're overwriting the value of topicid everytime you loop. I don't know how exactly you want your topicid to look like but a possible way to avoid this would be:

```
$_SESSION['topicid'] = array();

while($row = $topics->fetch_assoc()) {
$_SESSION['topicid'][] = $topic_id;
...
```

Comment: Thank Osuwariboy, however how would I call the correct topic_id in my second php file (send_post.php)?

Comment: When you create the HTML for each post, can't you include some information that would help you call the correct topic_id in your send_post? Like having a hidden input field with a value containing the ID you want or having the ID/name of the post control being "post_123456"?

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to the this is:
 ">to your next page // this will attach specific ids to each link during loop

Afterwards, go to your next page and use the $_GET method to get the id send via url...then apply it to ur query there

Answer (score -1):

`$topic_id= 0` //set this before the loop

```
while(){...
.....
```

`$topic_id++;` //increment id by one for each loop

`echo $topic_id` // if you want to print the values of the id
 `<a href="nextpage.php?id='".$$topic_id."'">to your next page</a>` // concatenate specific id to selected link

`}`// close while loop

in your nextpage.php

`$variable_name=$_GET['$topic_id'];`// this way you get the specific id concatenated to the particular link clicked